# Table row fills remaining height Chrome vs. Firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a code that acts differently on Firefox and Chrome.

The behaviour I want is the one on Firefox. I want to reproduce it on Chrome without success.

In the following code, the idea is that the `tr class="spacer"` fills the remaining height below the the `tr class="family"` rows so they would be displayed at the top of the `tr class="category"` row.

On Chrome this is completely inconsistent...

```css
.category th {
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.family {
  height: 70px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Family</th>
      <th>Info</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="category">
      <th rowspan="3">Category 1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="family">
      <td>Family 1</td>
      <td>Many different things</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="category">
      <th rowspan="4">Category 2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="family">
      <td>Family 2</td>
      <td>Other things</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="family">
      <td>Family 3</td>
      <td>Way more things</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="spacer">
      <td colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp, I rewrite your code like this. Hope this help you.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .custom th {
      height: 200px;
      background: red;
    }
    
    .custom td {
      height: 70px;
      background: blue;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Family</th>
        <th>Info</th>
      </tr>

      <tr class="custom">
        <th rowspan="3">Category 1</th>
        <td>Family 1</td>
        <td>Many different things</td>
      </tr>
      <!-- Add 2 spacer for enough 3 row because rowspan = 3 -->
      <tr class="spacer">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="spacer">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="custom">
        <th rowspan="4">Category 2</th>
        <td>Family 2</td>
        <td>Other things</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="custom">
        <td>Family 3</td>
        <td>Way more things</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="spacer">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="spacer">
        <td colspan="3"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that possibility but for my application it would be a pain to implement (the view is auto generated a certain way). So if I could keep the HTML like it is and only change the CSS that would be the best

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is how you structure your table but I have no solution using html tables.

I would rather use the css grid property. It needs a little bit more code but it provides in my Opinion more options a better responsiveness and so on.

I wrote down some code to display the same as you want with the tables. Of course you can modify the code to make it work more like you planned but it‘s a basic structure.

Html:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div>Category</div>
  <div>Family</div>
  <div>Info</div>

  <div class="first">
    <div class="grid-category">Category 1</div>
    <div class="family">Family 1</div>
    <div class="family">Many different things</div>
  </div>

  <div class="second">
    <div class="grid-category">Category 2</div>
    <div class="family">Family 2</div>
    <div class="family">Many different things</div>
    <div class="family">Family 3</div>
    <div class="family">Many different things</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.grid-category {
  min-height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.family {
  height: 70px;
  background: blue;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 16px auto auto;
}

.first,
.second {
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
}

.grid-category {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a great option! But I see no differences in the HTML, maybe a bad copy / paste?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I copied the wrong code. I will paste the right code later